# Paypal to send transaction id to my return url

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I want Paypal to send the transaction id when the payment on my site is completed to my return url. It did so by dafault on sandbox, but it won't do it on live. I have turned on auto-return, but it returns without any variables.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled IPN? IPN should POSt all that kind of data back to your return URL so it's up to you to capture it all.

PDT(Payment data transfer) should POST data back to your notify URL also.
I'm pretty sure it should be this - $_POST["txn_id"]